# Android AVD 2.3.3 w/ Google APIs on Intel Vs ARM

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I, step-by-step, install and run an Android AVD 2.3.3 using Intel rather than ARM? Can I do so on all dev systems? (e.g. Linux, OSX, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the Intel x86 emulator images is covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

> Can I do so on all dev systems? (e.g. Linux, OSX, ...)

The system requirements for the use of the Intel x86 emulator images is covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm). While all Android SDK development platforms are supported, not all CPUs are, and the "step-by-step" instructions vary by OS.

**UPDATE**

My apologies regarding the Google APIs. There is no support for Google APIs on all the x86 variants, as Intel has not prepared them. At this point, it is exceedingly unlikely that there will ever be an x86 image with Google API support.

Comment: Intel x86 Emu Accel (HAXM) not comp. w/ Linux, which I am on. SDK manager shows Atom image for API 17,16,15,10 so 2.3.3 is there, but w/o Google APIs, which I asked about in the title..

Comment: @Robottinosino: HAXM is not, but the emulator is. I am using it right now. If you tread the documentation, you will find a section about configuring KVM on Linux to use the x86 emulator images. With regards to Google APIs, see my update.

Comment: Thank you. In short: 2.3.3 needs to run in ARM emu if I want to use Google Maps, for example?

Comment: @Robottinosino: Maps V2 will not run in that emulator anyway, AFAIK. Maps V1 would require the ARM emulator.